# starting a terminal in desktop (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments

Anyone know how to start a (Linux) terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 desktop? I could not find an icon for it on the task menu bar along the side of the desktop. :(

Thanks ahead!!!

Comment: ctrl+alt+t, or Dash -> terminal

Answer (score 0):

This link will teach you how to start a terminal irrespective of your desktop environment.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Alternatively for a full screen terminal you can type

```
CTRL+ALT+F1
```

Comment: Once you have started a terminal with CTRL+ALT+F1, how do you exit? I tried "quit" and "exit" and I'm still stuck at the command prompt!

Comment: ctrl+alt+f7 in ununtu 14.04